# How to convert the existing helm chart to a set of Kubernetes manifests?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

How can I obtain just a set of Kubernetes yaml files filled in with default Helm chart parameters, so that I can use kubectl apply -f ./manifests to run the required service?

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [`helm template`](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_template/) command:

> Render chart templates locally and display the output.
>
> Any values that would normally be looked up or retrieved in-cluster
> will be faked locally. Additionally, none of the server-side testing
> of chart validity (e.g. whether an API is supported) is done.
>
> `helm template [NAME] [CHART] [flags]`

e.g:

`helm template my-chart stable/chart --output-dir /home/user/my-chart`

Then you can use `kubectl apply -f /home/user/my-chart`